# How to interpolate two <a> tags with the Trans component that react-i18next provides?

Tags: reactjs, react-i18next

I want to interpolate a text with two links so that it looks like this:

Image of the output I am looking for
[image: Image of the output I am looking for]

My code is this and based on the react-i18next documentation:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useTranslation, Trans } from 'react-i18next';
import { policies } from 'config/copies';
import 'styles/components/overlay/PassengerPolicies.scss';

const PassengerPolicies = () => {
  const { t } = useTranslation('seats');

  return (
    <>
      <div className="passenger-policies-label">
        <Trans i18nKey="user_messages_unread" t={t}>
          text
          <a target="_blank" href={policies.termsAndConditionsUrl}>
            text
          </a>
          text
          <a target="_blank" href={policies.noticeOfPrivacy}>
            text
          </a>
        </Trans>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default PassengerPolicies;
```

And this is my seats.json file with the translation:

```
{
  "user_messages_unread": "By continuing I agree to the <1>terms and conditions</1> and the <1>privacy notice.</1>"
}
```

The problem I have is that the two links added in this way add the same href and therefore send me to the same place. Anyone have an idea what the problem is or how to do this?

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(policies )` ?

Comment: This is my policies object @SinanYaman
`{termsAndConditionsUrl: "https://domain.com.mx/terminos-condiciones.html", noticeOfPrivacy: "https://domain.com.mx/aviso-privacidad-comercial.html"}`
The two links send me to the desired place but in the interpolation add only the first one.

Answer (score 2):

Your JSON entry needs to use the correct nodes as references:

```json
{
  "user_messages_unread": "By continuing I agree to the <1>terms and conditions</1> and the <3>privacy notice.</3>"
}
```

Otherwise it's reusing the same tag for each as they're both declared as `<1>`

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a link to a paragraph like this:

```
<p>
  By continuing I agree to the 
 <a href={policies.termsAndConditionsUrl}>terms and conditions</a> 
 and the 
 <a href={policies.noticeOfPrivacy}>privacy notice</a>
</p>
```

This is a codebox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-davinci-dc127?file=/src/App.js

Comment: That's fine but I need the translations, this app uses several languages.